# Meaning of this coffeescript construct?

Tags: coffeescript

In the excellent paths.js library, I see this construct being used:

```
({a,b}) ->
    c= a * b
    #...
```

I can see that it's a *very* concise way of unpacking an argument dictionary, but I see no mention of it in the coffeescript documentation.

Interestingly,

`{x,y}` and   `({x,y})->` compile into very different javascript constructs.

Is there an explanation of the correct use of these in the documentation anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

That's just a [destructured object assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) hidden inside a function's argument list. Given this:

```
o = { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C' }
```

you can say this:

```
{a, b} = o
```

as a short hand for:

```
a = o.a
b = o.b
```

So this"

```
({a,b}) ->
    c = a * b
```

pulls the values of `a` and `b` keys out of the function's argument (which is an object of some kind) and assigns them to local `a` and `b` variables. In other words, it is the same as:

```
(obj) ->
    a = obj.a
    b = obj.b
    c = a * b
```